Proving quantum operator relationship used in derivation of Radial Schrodinger Equation
In the derivation of the Radial Schrodinger Equation for central potentials, I have seen the following relationship used:
$$
r^2p^2 = L^2+(\bf{r}\cdot\bf{p})^2-i\hbar(\bf{r}\cdot\bf{p})
$$
and I have seen a long proof of this using the cartesian coordinate form of these operators (i.e. $$L=(yp_z-zp_y)\hat{\bf{x}}-(xp_z-zp_x)\hat{\bf{y}}+(xp_y-yp_x)\hat{\bf{z}}$$ and so on) with the usual commutation relations ($[x,p_x]=i\hbar$ etc)
But I was trying to do it in spherical polar coordinate form, and almost got the right answer but seem to have made a mistake somewhere, as I seem to get $$
r^2p^2 = L^2+(\bf{r}\cdot\bf{p})^2+i\hbar(\bf{r}\cdot\bf{p})
$$ instead (note the sign difference). Can someone spot my mistake? Here's my working:
$
L = rp_\theta\hat{\bf{\phi}} - rp_\phi\hat{\bf{\theta}}
$
so
$
L^2 = rp_\theta rp_\theta + rp_\phi rp_\phi
$
and similarly we have:
$
\bf{r}\cdot\bf{p} = rp_r
$
So
$
L^2 + (\bf{r}\cdot\bf{p})^2 = rp_\theta rp_\theta + rp_\phi rp_\phi + rp_rrp_r
$
And if I use the commutation relations: $[r,p_r]=i\hbar$, and $[r,p_\theta]=[r,p_\phi]=0$ (which I got from looking at the position representation of the operators), I arrive at my relationship, which is out by a sign difference from the expected result:
$
L^2 + (\bf{r}\cdot\bf{p})^2 + i\hbar rp_r = r^2(p_r^2 + p_\theta^2 + p_\phi^2)
$

Your mistake happens in the last line. When you use the commutator. You get $r^2p^2=rppr+i\hbar rp$.
But you still have it on the right side of your equation. Push it to the left so you get the minus from there.

Thanks, but why do I need to replace the $rrp_rp_r$ on the right with an $rp_rp_rr$? I could see that being necessary if $(r\cdot p)^2 = rp_rp_rr$ rather than $rp_rrp_r$ but I think it is supposed to be the latter ... I have come up with a possible answer to my own question, which I'll post below and perhaps you can comment if it's correct or not ....

I have managed to find a solution but I would appreciate some verification if the logic of this solution is correct ...
So I can make it work if I should interpret any vector operator "square", $\bf{V}^2$, as actually doing $\bf{V}^\dagger\cdot\bf{V}$ where $\bf{V}^\dagger$ is the same vector operator but with all the operator components hermitian conjugated. Note this does not apply to the $(p\cdot r)^2$, so writing the identity out more verbosely I would have:
$
(r^\dagger\cdot r)(p^\dagger\cdot p) = L^\dagger\cdot L + (r\cdot p)(r\cdot p) - i\hbar(r\cdot p)
$
Giving:
$
r^\dagger r(p_r^\dagger p_r + p_\theta^\dagger p_\theta + p_\phi^\dagger p_\phi ) = p_\theta^\dagger r^\dagger r p_\theta + p_\phi^\dagger r^\dagger r p_\phi + rp_rrp_r - i\hbar rp_r
$
Now we know $r^\dagger = r$ but I can show $p_r^\dagger = p_r - 2i\hbar r^{-1}$ (integrate by parts in position representation).Se we first replace the $rp_rrp_r$ on the rhs with $rrp_rp_r - i\hbar rp_r$ by using the commutation relation, and then replace the $rrp_rp_r$ with $rr(p_r^\dagger + 2i\hbar r^{-1})p_r$ using the expression for the hermitian conjugate of $p_r$. This all gives:
$
r^\dagger r(p_r^\dagger p_r + p_\theta^\dagger p_\theta + p_\phi^\dagger p_\phi ) = p_\theta^\dagger r^\dagger r p_\theta + p_\phi^\dagger r^\dagger r p_\phi + rr(p_r^\dagger + 2i\hbar r^{-1})p_r - 2i\hbar rp_r
$
and since the $r^{-1}$ cancels one of the $r$ then the terms with $\hbar$ cancel on the rhs and given everything else commutes and $r^\dagger=r$, the lhs = rhs.
Do other people agree with this solution?
